# Kerberos IIS Authentication over HTTP

Tags: kerberos

I've reviewed the RFCs and am pretty familiar with Kerberos.

It seems to me that over a non-encrypted link (HTTP), Kerberos doesn't leak the user's password (or hash based challenge/response like NTLMv1/v2) and/or is susceptible to a reply attack.

In a properly designed implementation of Kerberos, is HTTP authentication considered secure over a non-encrypted link?

Answer (score 3):

Kerberos authentication on HTTP will [encapsulate Kerberos ticket inside a SPNEGO token](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.5.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/spnego_protocol.html) and will not expose user credentials. Replay attack is stopped by [authenticators](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82839/kerberos-replay-attack). But there is a possibility to do a active MITM attack where you would prevent server from receiving captured authenticator. Please see [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.109.4133&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper for more details.